# HTML empty space on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

If I add width to any element on page which is larger than screen than on mobile devices (or Developer Tools enabled Touch simulation) I get empty space below footer.

Original site which has problem: https://www.kanemi.lv/oskarsvesters.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body style="width: 2000px;">
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're describing, but setting scale might help. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Problem is that it is not possible to leave horizontal scroll and avoid empty space on bottom. Scale does not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    min-width: 0;
}
```

try this

Comment: This does not help to leave horizontal scroll but avoid empty space on bottom.